# Background image to ignore padding-top CSS

Tags: css, image, background, padding

I have a background-image on the first section of my site however there is padding-top on that section in order to seperate the first title from the navbar. Is there a way I can get the background image to over ride the top padding?

Thanks

HTML

```
<nav>

        <a href="#getting-his-start"><b>Getting his Start</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#cinematic-revolution"><b>Cinematic Revolution</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#experimental-phase"><b>The Experimental Phase</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#logos-made-to-last"><b>Logos Made to Last</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#the-nect-big-thing"><b>The Next Big Thing</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#his-influence-today"><b>His Influence Today</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </nav>

    <section class="start">

        <h2 id="getting-his-start">Getting his Start</h2>
```

CSS for background image

```
.start {
background-image: url(../images/goldenarmamend.png);
background-position: top right;
height: 100%vh;
width: 100%vw;
```

}

CSS for h3 to have space above

```
h3 {
font-size: 1.5em;
margin-top: 3em;
margin-bottom: 0.7em;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

}

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: So you want first Nav bar then Title on the white background and then the Background-image section?

Comment: no I want the background image to not have a gap between it and the nav bar however there is top padding on the first section so there is a gap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a margin-top instead of padding-top and move the title up with negative margin top.
IF you can share code snippet on that section can give a exact answer.

Comment: it's better to consider adding comments (since you have enough reputation) then adding a broad answer as we don't have enough information to provide relevant/precise answer

Comment: I have added the snippets of code that are relevant

Comment: @TaraMcAllister you code is still not relevant and contain mistakes ... also why this answer got accpeted? it doesn't provide any solution