# Background image to ignore padding on section?

Tags: css, background-image, navbar, padding

I have a background image for the first section of my site that I need to touch the nav bar. The arm is the background image. It needs to touch the nav bar for the design.
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEj9y.png)

The first section starts with a header (h3) which has padding-top on it:

```
h3 {
font-size: 1.5em;
margin-top: 3em;
margin-bottom: 0.7em;
text-transform: uppercase; }
```

I need the background to "ignore" the padding so theres no gap between it and the navbar.

the CSS for the background image

```
.start {
background-image: url(../images/goldenarmamend.png);
background-position: top right;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: `h3` appear before the `.start` element? What does your markup look like?

Comment: `100%vh` and `100%vw` are invalid. You should use `%` or `vh/vw`, not both together.

Comment: Why don't you place the `background-image` on the section?

Comment: you already posted the same question and you didn't do the effort to improve it by adding the relevant code and show the issue ... if you want us to help you, you need to make it easy for us to understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image to ignore padding-top CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077688/background-image-to-ignore-padding-top-css)

Comment: @temaniAfif you will find that I did go to the effort to show all the code that was relevant to the question and you have no need to leave comments saying i deserve no answer when i am trying my best

Comment: i saw both question and nothing help us to understand ... simply put your self as a third person and see the code you added in both question. Do you think we can even make it a working code to see the output ? In this code there is no HTML, the image path is relative. In the other question it's almost the same. Am helping by commenting like this. I could simply downvote/vote to close and leave

Comment: I am trying my best I am new to this. There is no need to threaten me with down votes

Comment: instead of saying I am not doing this and that why not tell me what i need to show so i understand

Comment: you simply need to show us something that works in oder we can see the issue :) that's what am trying to explain. You know the issue and you saw it but what you have provided we can see anything, so consider adding a working snippet where we can see the image and the padding-top issue

Answer (score 0):

remove background position...

```
    .start {
    background-image: url(../images/goldenarmamend.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

set right value as per your need in pixel or em.

Comment: either use `%` or `vh/vw` not both.

Comment: yeah shubham u r right i didn't see that portion i'm just copy pasted